# python web scraping with scrapy spider

Tags: python, string, web-scraping, scrapy

I am writing simple spider using scrapy, In which i want to add some mechanism to find out what kind of content I am crawling.

Say for example i have list of strings:

```
The resource you are looking for has expired
The resource is not available
```

Like that i have thousands of strings. Now i want to check whether the crawled content have any one this. How can i do this python ?

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    try:
        content = items['body']
       ----------------------------- // How can i proceed further.
    except pymssql.Error, e:
        print ("error")
```

in the "content" i have the crawled information.

I have:

1. using string comparison
2. have to create lookup file and do the matching

But i wanted to know is their any way to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a list of strings you want to check for and use built-in [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
terms = [
    'The resource you are looking for has expired',
    'The resource is not available'
]

has_terms = any(term in content for term in terms)
```

Note that `terms` list should be defined outside of the `process_item()` to avoid having it redefined each time `process_item()` is called. A good idea would be having it configured in the project settings.

Also, if are you going to skip items that have any of the defined terms, think about moving the check to the spider level. This would help to avoid having an overhead of passing item from the spider to the pipeline.

Comment: Hi alecxe, Thank you for the reply and how can i move this step to  the spider level. I am new to this Can you help me

Comment: @Backtrack could you show the code of your spider? Thanks.

Comment: I am using portia to build my spider. So i am little confused now, like which part of the code i should share

Comment: @Backtrack this is the one where you return or yield `Item`s.

Comment: I have added my setting.py file. I am using my own SQL  pipeline

Comment: @Backtrack okay, then just easier would be to continue doing it in the pipeline.

Comment: If i wish to move the spider level later, How can i do., Is there any tutorial or example. Can you please share that. ?

Comment: @Backtrack I would love too, but the problem is I haven't personally used portia - not familiar with your setup.

Comment: Okay :). But if i use Scrapy is there any way to do this ?

Comment: @Backtrack should not be difficult to implement - basically you would just not yield/return items if `has_terms` is `True`. Thanks.

Comment: One another question .. Where should i "has_terms" include this in the scrapy spider. Is there any example ???

Comment: How the implementation should be in the Scrapy spider ?? Can you please provide me some tips to do this ?